# Are limits allowed in a function?

Tags: functions

I wasn't sure how to specify my question correctly in my title, so I hope that my language is not too offensive.

What I would like to do is specify a function such as f(x) = .999... * x, such that f(1) represents the largest value less than 1.

I'm not sure if A: this somehow violates f's membership of the functions, and B: how this should be correctly specified if not A.  My thoughts are that .999... is equivalent to 1, and that .999...9 is ambiguous or implies that the sequence of digits is finite and therefore not the largest value less than 1.

Again I apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is only useful if it can specify the largest $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x < 1$, but does such an $x$ even exist?

Well, let's look at all the real numbers between $0$ (the next lowest integer) and $1$ (the upper limit of possible values): let the set $S$ be defined as $S:=\{x| x \in \mathbb{R},\ 0<x< 1 \}$, if $S$ has a largest value then we can specify your function.

The **least upper bound** of our set $S$ is the value that bounds $S$ from above, also called the supremum, which is the largest member of the set, or (if the set has no largest value) is the smallest value possible that is not in the set but every member of the set is smaller than.

Our set $S$ has the obvious upper bound of one, but because one is not in the set itself, the set is infinite*

So, no you can not write such a function.

**However**, so long as you have only one 'output' values for every one of your domain values, then it is a function. So, you can use limits or other things in your function.

---

*A more rigorous proof:

Define the set $S$ as above. Now we can describe a subset of $S$, $Q$, such that 
 $$Q := \left\{y | \ \ \ y \in S \wedge \ y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 9 * 10^{-i} \right\}$$
if $S$ has a highest value it will be in $Q$ because $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 9 * 10^{-i}\right) = 1 \ \ \ \ .$$
By the same logic, we can see that the set $Q$ is infinite, therefore it has no largest value, and so by extension $S$ has no largest value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no largest value less than 1.  The limit of the sequence {.9, .99, .999, ...} is just 1.

A function is any assignment of a single value to any number in whatever you declare to be the domain of your function.  So you can use limits or words and you have a function, as long as there's only one number assigned to each number in your domain, even if you haven't explicitly written it down.